# Как использовать Enter вместо Кнопок в одной форме

Tags: javascript, html, form

Добрый вечер всем. Как использовать Enter вместо нажатия Кнопок в одной форме (кнопки пусть остаются также). Как можно реализовать  данное решение? (использовать две формы нельзя). (Вообще, дальше данные отрабатываются в php).

```html
<form method="get"> <!-- два поля input  -->
           Поиск по пользователю:
           <input class="input_text" type="text" name="user" id="user"></input>
           <input class="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Поиск"></input>
           <br>
           
           Поиск по найденому:
           <input type="text" name="userf"  id="userf" ></input>
           <input class="button" type="submit" name="buttonf" value="Поиск"></input>
</form>
```

Comment: а при чем тут java?

Comment: и php не при делах.

Comment: -что бы сориентировать по мыслям тех кто будет советовать, что все варианты принимаются.

Answer (score 0):

Если ajax (без перезагрузки страницы):

```js
var $frm = $("#form"),
    $inputs = $frm.find("input");

$frm.submit(function(e) {
  
    $inputs.each(function() {
    
        if( $(this).is(":focus") ) {
        
            console.log('i\'m ' + $(this).attr("name") + '. ajax me, bro!');
        
        }
    
    })
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
})
```

```css
#form input[type="submit"]{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="search_by_user" placeholder="search by user" />
    <input type="text" name="search_in_found" placeholder="search in found" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Если переход (с перезагрузкой страницы или переходом на файл-обработчик):

```js
var query, 
    $frm = $("#form"),
    $inputs = $frm.find("input"),
    url = ( $frm.attr("action") ) ? $frm.attr("action") : "";
    
$frm.submit(function(e) {
  
    $inputs.each(function() {
    
        if( $(this).is(":focus") ) {
        
            query = "?" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).val();
            
            console.log(url + query);
        
            //window.location.href = query;
            // раскомментированная, данная строчка совершит get запрос.
        }
    
    })
    
    return false;
    
})
```

```css
#form input[type="submit"]{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="some.php" method="get" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="search_by_user" placeholder="search by user" />
    <input type="text" name="search_in_found" placeholder="search in found" />
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: скажите, а что значит "если  переход"? это java? и если да, то почему в html также ajax ссылка ?

Comment: Первый вариант, если вы используете ajax для получения результата запроса. Второй вариант, если после сабмита формы должен произойти переход на страницу action (если обработка формы происходит в том же файле, где и сама форма, тогда будет перезагрузка страницы с get запросом).

Comment: @OlegZolotarenko java и javascript - разные вещи

Comment: И в html не "ajax ссылка", а подключение библиотеки jquery